# Best way to escape quotes in dto string field in Spring MVC using taglibs

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC + Web Flow. I bind my dto's with Springs form:input jsp tags. When user types string with quotes and goes to next step all is good, all data in db. But when he decides return back and check previous page, data retrieving from db and there is a problem with escaping of quotes (all info after a quote are missing). What is the best way to escape string before it written to jsp input.

htmlEscape="true" - is not good for me because it escapes all other things (but I don't want it)

I tried to create a class

```
public class StringQuotesEscapeEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport     {

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        Object value = getValue();
        return (value != null ? value.toString().replace("\"", "&quot;") :     "");
    }
}
```

and to register it like this

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdviceConfig {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringQuotesEscapeEditor());
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work for me.. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you want "other things"? If you write the value to HTML output, you'd want it. Try adding value "abc<b>xyz". Without escaping `<`, you get "abc**xyz**"

Comment: Using backslash (\\) to quote the value won't work for HTML. In HTML, quotes much be escaped as `&quot;`.

Comment: @Andreas Because users want quotes. Other symbols have lower priority for me. If I use htmlEscape="true" then if user goes forward and back he will see escaped sequences instead of real data. About second comment, Yes i tried this way also.

Comment: @Andreas Did I choose correct Spring extension point for my purpose?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by your user seeing escaped sequences. If user enters `a<b>c"d&e` in an `input type="text"` field, then that value is posted and saved in your database. When generating HTML to display that value, the code generating the HTML should escape the text, so the generated output is `a&lt;b&gt;c&quot;d&amp;e`, which will display correctly. If HTML is generated by JSP, then `<c:out>` will escape it for you. Don't know why you are trying to backslash escape the value at all.

Comment: I see `a&lt;b&gt;c&quot;d&amp;e` is in input when displaying saved with escape html= true

Comment: Sounds like you are double-escaping. If you escape the text in the controller *and* escape the text by using `<c:out>`, then you get what you see. Stop escaping in the controller. That is not the controllers job. Its job is to provide the data. It is the job of your view technology (JSP?) to correctly render the data.

Comment: Maybe it is webflow doing something? Because I it doesn't work even without controller escaping.